# Google map API return incorrect result for searches

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to coding in android and I am trying to use the google map API to display places nearby.

My code is:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            mMap.clear();
            String search = "cvs"
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, search);
            Object[] dataTransfer = new Object[2];
            dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            dataTransfer[1] = url;
            GetNearbyData getNearbyData = new GetNearbyData();
            getNearbyData.execute(dataTransfer);
        }

     private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String 
                           nearbyPlace) {

        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new 
 StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "{MY_KEY}");
        return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    }
```

the URL output is:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7692494,-73.9842065&radius=10000&type=cvs&sensor=true&key={MY_KEY}

The problem starts when I change the search word, when I put (under the URL type) cvs/parks/starbucks... (and probably other places) I keep getting the same result.  For example: if my location is central park NY, I keep getting results for 
Chrysler Building
Hotel Pennsylvania
Hudson New York and more.
Those palaces are not related to my search word (cvs/parks/starbucks...)
Important note is that for banks I do get banks' results.

Can anyone explain me how to solve this problem? why for some words I do get correct results and for other I do not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that none of `cvs`, `parks` or `starbucks` belong to the list of supported types that you can use in nearby search. You can consult the list of supported types in the official Places API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

I believe you have to use a `keyword` parameter when you construct the URL instead of the `type` parameter.

> **keyword** — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

For example if I search 'cvs'

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7692494%2C-73.9842065&radius=10000&keyword=cvs&key=MY_API_KEY`

I can see places that are relevant for this search as shown in my screenshot

[image]

Search for 'parks'

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7692494%2C-73.9842065&radius=10000&keyword=parks&key=MY_API_KEY`

gives me the following results

[image]

Finally search for 'starbucks'

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7692494%2C-73.9842065&radius=10000&keyword=starbucks&key=MY_API_KEY`

returns Starbucks places

[image]

I hope this helps!